# Value not being added to array in PHP foreach statement

Tags: php, arrays

I am having an issue with a foreach statement where I try to add a extra value to the array, it seemed to work fine, but now all of the sudden it no longer works.

When I do a var_dump inside the for loop of the value added to `$application['agency']`it shows the value but as soon as I leave the for statement the and run `var_dump($applications);` it no longer has the values in it.

I am sure i am missing something small but cannot see it. Can anybody please assist?

**Code:**

```
foreach($applications as $application) {
        if (is_array($application)) {
            $agenciessarray=db_select("select agency_name from `agencies` where `agency_id`=".db_quote($application['agency_id']));
            //var_dump($agenciessarray);
            //echo '<br/>';
            $application['agency'] = $agenciessarray[0]['agency_name'];
            //var_dump($application['agency']);
            //echo '<br/>';
        }
    }

var_dump($applications);
```

**Result:**

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> array(7) { 
        ["application_id"] => string(4) "1002" 
        ["first_names"] => string(6) "asdads" 
        ["surname"] => string(6) "asdasd" 
        ["id_number"] => string(6) "123123" 
        ["cell_number"] => string(4) "sadf" 
        ["email_address"] => string(0) "" 
        ["agency_id"] => string(1) "2" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(7) { 
        ["application_id"] => string(4) "1003" 
        ["first_names"] => string(6) "asdads" 
        ["surname"] => string(6) "asdasd" 
        ["id_number"] => string(6) "123123" 
        ["cell_number"] => string(4) "sadf" 
        ["email_address"] => string(0) "" 
        ["agency_id"] => string(1) "2" 
    } 
    [2]=> array(7) { 
        ["application_id"] => string(4) "1004" 
        ["first_names"] => string(6) "asdads" 
        ["surname"] => string(6) "asdasd" 
        ["id_number"] => string(6) "123123" 
        ["cell_number"] => string(4) "sadf" 
        ["email_address"] => string(0) "" 
        ["agency_id"] => string(1) "2" 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you modify local copy of the `$applications` array element. It exists only inside the loop. You need to access the actual variable inside the array.

One of the solutions is to include the array key `$k` to the loop and then refer to the array element by it.

```
foreach($applications as $k => $application) {
            // .......
            $applications[$k]['agency'] = $agenciessarray[0]['agency_name'];
            // .......
        }
    }
```

[PHP documentation for foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) also recommends a way of doing it by passing variable to the loop by reference. Ex:

```
foreach($applications as &$application) {
            // .......
            $application['agency'] = $agenciessarray[0]['agency_name'];
            // .......
        }
    }
```